# React Routes from a Json array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my JSON array data

```
"portfolio": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "src": "./img/placeholder-image.png",
      "title": "Ahuse",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspenmdisse varius eim in eros elementum tristique",
      "link": "<Link to='webdev'>Read More</Link>"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "src": "./img/placeholder-image-1.png",
      "title": "App Dashboard",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspenmdisse varius eim in eros elementum tristique",
      "link": "<Link to='appdev'>Read More</Link>"
    }
  ]
```

Here is my portfolio.jsx file code snippet

```
<div className="portfolio--section--container">
        {data?.portfolio?.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="portfolio--section--card">
            <div className="portfolio--section--img">
              <img src={item.src} alt="Placeholder" />
            </div>
            <div className="portfolio--section--card--content">
              <div>
                <h3 className="portfolio--section--title">{item.title}</h3>
                <p className="text-md">{item.description}</p>
              </div>
              <p className="text-sm portfolio--link">
                {item.link}</p>
```

I would like when a user clicks read more to be redirected to another component/page and read more about the project. I'm not sure where I'll put the React Routers. How can I achieve this?

- Read more => webdev component page
- Read more => appdev component page
- Read more => digital marketing component page

Here is a snippet of [the expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMcv9.jpg).
Here is a snippet of [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9C07.png).

Comment: The approach of saving a _`Link` component_ in your JSON data is not correct. You can simply save the `to` part of it in your JSON and inside the the component render the `Link` component directly as: `<Link to={data.link} />`

Comment: When reading json it will not parse as html ( there is a html parse component though).. Try what moonstar-x says and keep the component in react and only use the link from the data...

Answer (score 2):

You can't write Link in your JSON data. Just write the name of the components where you want to redirect.

```
"portfolio": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "src": "./img/placeholder-image.png",
      "title": "Ahuse",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspenmdisse varius eim in eros elementum tristique",
      "link": "webdevRead"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "src": "./img/placeholder-image-1.png",
      "title": "App Dashboard",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspenmdisse varius eim in eros elementum tristique",
      "link": "appdev"
    }
  ]
```

and in your portfolio.jsx

```
<div className="portfolio--section--container">
        {data?.portfolio?.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="portfolio--section--card">
            <div className="portfolio--section--img">
              <img src={item.src} alt="Placeholder" />
            </div>
            <div className="portfolio--section--card--content">
              <div>
                <h3 className="portfolio--section--title">{item.title}</h3>
                <p className="text-md">{item.description}</p>
              </div>
            
              <Link className="text-sm portfolio--link" to={item.link}>Read More</Link>
```